# Is there a way to change the argument name of a nested function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, scipy

So the easiest way to illustrate my question is through an example. Let's say I want to write a function `function(a=None,b=None,c=None)`, this function will only take two arguments at a time and the third one will be left blank. For any two arguments that one gives to the function it will return the missing one such that `a+b=c`. So for example `function(a=5, c=15)` would return 10 and for `function(a = 5, b = 10)` it would return 15. Now for the sake of the argument let's say that `a` could not be written as a function of `b` and `c`, or its simply too complicated to find a closed solution (this is clearly not the case here because to find `a`, I could simply say `a = c-b`). Anyway, if I was to write such a function I'd do something like this:

```
#import a root finder
from scipy.optimize import newton

def function(a= None, b= None, c = None): 
    #find the missing parameter:
    vars = [a,b,c]
    comp = vars.index(None)
    
    if comp == 0: 
        def aux_fun(a): 
            return (a+b-c)
    elif comp == 1:
        def aux_fun(b):
            return (a+b-c)
    else:
        def aux_fun(c):
            return (a+b-c)
    
    return newton(aux_fun, 0)
```

I have not found a solution to this other than writing 3 different functions and calling the correct one in `newton`. This works for this small example but if I have a bigger problem let's say with 100 variables writing 100 functions is not pretty.

My question is: is there any way such that I only have to write `aux_fun` once and change its parameter based on the missing parameter from `function`

Thanks a lot for your answers!

Comment: It's unclear what argument you're actually trying to call aux_fun with.  But `vars.index(None)` will tell you the index of the missing argument.  From this index, you can then deduce any information you need.

Comment: I'm having a hard time with your example as it seems like you have a concrete example in mind but are instead giving us an example that isn't so much simplified but oversimplified to the point where it doesn't address what you need to be done. Have you thought about having your named arguments called in the first function returned in a different order that, in the second function, you call as positional arguments.

Comment: @FrankYellin, yeah that is a way better way to find the missing argument, I will change it.

Comment: @hrokr , I'm sorry that it seems like an over simplification but my problem can be summarized as, __how do I create a function that returns a value for the missing argument, without having to create nested functions for each of the possible missing arguments?__ .

Comment: We need a [mcve].  Word problems, even when expressed with bold are a pain to work with.

Comment: I think you have two issues here but at least one for sure. First, your example doesn't work (also the code doesn't but that's beside the point). You have exactly said you're defining an algebraic relationship, but imagine it doesn't work. The second part is that you said what you want to change the name of a parameter, but that seems to be overly complex. Unfortunately, because of the example, we can't get a good bead on if this something you actually need vs being functionally fixated on the solution you think you need.

Comment: Sorry @hrokr I just re run my example and It worked as intended, what error does it throw?. When I run `function(a= 10, c = 25)`  I get 15 which is the expected answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't fully grasped what you are trying to do, but I don't think you quite understand how `newton` works.

`optimize.newton` is going to call your function with

```
 func(x, a, b, c ...)
```

where `x` is a scalar or array of the size of the initial value, the `x0`.  The other arguments are passed via the `args` tuple.   This pattern of passing an iteration variable and `args` to the function is widely used in these `scipy.optimize` functions.  I've answered a number of questions regarding these arguments.

```
 newton(func, x0, args=(a,b,c))
```

These aren't keyword arguments.

Read and experiment with the examples in the docs.  People often mess up the `args` tuple.  And then explore a few small examples of your own before seriously trying to do this 'renaming'.

## edit

This might work - I haven't tested it:

```
def function(a= None, b= None, c = None): 
    #find the missing parameter:
    vars = [a,b,c]
    comp = vars.index(None)

    def aux_fun(x):
        vars[comp] = x
        a,b,c = vars
        return (a+b-c)
    
    return newton(aux_fun, 0)
```

Comment: Let me try to explain a bit better. I'm trying to pass a function to newton `aux_fun` such that the sole argument of this function is the missing argument from `function`. So for instance if I called `function(a = 2, b = 5) ` i want the sole parameter of `aux_function` to be `c` (`def aux_function(c)`). In that way when I put that function into newton I'd give me the solution for `c`. In what I have in mind I don't need to pass the `args` tuple because the function that I'm optimizing only has one argument

Comment: So `a,b` will be accessible from the calling function?  Without seeing working code, such as your 3 functions, I don't think we can help.  Keep in mind that any good answer will provide working code.  And for that we prefer to have a working example to start from, and to compare with.

Comment: I changed a bit the problem so it includes a working example. I'm sorry if it was unclear before (or even if it's still unclear). I'm open to suggestions in ways to improve my "asking skills".

Comment: I added an untested suggestion.

Comment: Yes it does work, I don't know if this breaks comment protocol but can you suggest a better name for my question ? I believe it does not correctly reflects the question.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is impossible.  Given a generic function f(a, b, c, d) = 0, there is no way to generically turn it into a set of functions a = f1(b, c, d), b = f2(a, c, d), etc.  You are entering the realm of symbolic computation.  You would need your code to understand trigonometry, algebra, calculus, exponentiation and logarithms.

---

Updating based on comments below.

So you want something like:

```
def aux_func(x):
    vars[comp] = x
    return f(*vars)
```

Comment: I dont believe so, keep in mind that I'm not looking for a closed form solution, that is what `newton` newton is for. If you look in my code all `aux_fun(.)` have exactly the same form except they take a different parameter.  If I had to write this problem a bit differently I'm saying f(a,b) = g(c) (where f and g are functions), I'm simply solving for a, b or c such that f - g = 0. It does not matter what the functional forms of f and g are because f - g = 0 will be solved by numerical methods (`newton` in this case).

Comment: But that's precisely my point.  Let's take an easy example like  a + sin b + exp(c).  Solving for 'a' is easy.  Solving for 'b' would be arcsin(-a - exp(c)).  Solving for c would be ln(-a - sin b). There is no systematic way to transform an equation like that.  You spend years learning algebra and trig to learn techniques that may or may not work for a given function.

Comment: Let me rephrase a bit, I'm solving the equation sin b + exp(c) = a. If I could find c as a function of the other two or b as a function of the other two, and that would be "hard" (they have different functional forms). But I can easily write a function that gives me the difference between both sides of the equation. That function would be f(a,b,c) = sin b + exp(c) - a, if I take any two arguments as given, lets say a and b that function could be written as f(c) and the `c` such that f(c) = 0 is  the answer that I'm looking for. At no point I have to find the closed form solution for c.